# server client initialization (only once) java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I have a client/server program(that use sockets) written in java. It has a multiple functions that establishing connections. For example:

```
public static void some_sender(byte[] x0, byte[] x1) //he is a server
{
   ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(8888);
   s.setSoTimeout(10000);
   Socket incoming=s.accept();
   ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(incoming.getOutputStream());
   ObjectInputStream ios = new ObjectInputStream(incoming.getInputStream());

   //some sending and receiving
   some_sender0(a);

}

public static void some_sender0(int a)
    {
       ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(8888);
       s.setSoTimeout(10000);
       Socket incoming=s.accept();
       ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(incoming.getOutputStream());
       ObjectInputStream ios = new ObjectInputStream(incoming.getInputStream());

       //some sending and receiving
    }
```

The same thing I have with client()

```
public static byte[] some_receiver(byte b)
{
   Socket s=new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8888);
   ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
   ObjectInputStream ios=new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
   //some sending and receiving
   byte[] t=some_receiver0(c);
   return m;
}

public static byte[] some_receiver0(byte c)
{
    Socket s=new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8888);
    ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    ObjectInputStream ios=new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    //some sending and receiving

    return y;
}
```

My question is how to execute(initialize server)

```
 ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(8888);
 s.setSoTimeout(10000);
 Socket incoming=s.accept();
 ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(incoming.getOutputStream());
 ObjectInputStream ios = new ObjectInputStream(incoming.getInputStream());
```

and (client)

```
 Socket s=new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8888);
 ObjectOutputStream oos=new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
 ObjectInputStream ios=new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
```

only once and use it in all nested functions.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Static fields or change it up and use instance variables (if you want to be more OO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Sotirios Delimanolis for advice. I decided to be more OO. Created a class that has two methods. one for starting Socket connection and assigning streams and second for closing evething. E.g.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class NetworkTransfers { 

public Socket s = null;
public ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
public ObjectInputStream ios = null;

public void activateNetwork()
{
    try {
        s = new Socket("IP-address", Port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        ios = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       

}

public void closeConnections()
{
    try {
        s.close();
        ios.close();
        oos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Pretty the same on server side.
Hope it will be hopeful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest putting them into Singleton classes which serve as the server/client controller.  Initialize them at appropriate times and make sure they have all the necessary getters (not setters) and utility methods so your other classes can work with the socket streams.

Comment: I will be very appreciated for code, since I'm not very good in Java